# Can I display a URL link in the ARPCONTACT property?

Tags: windows-installer

My msi is displaying the URL but not as link. Is there any way to dsiplay a URL link in the ARPCONTACT property of msi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Because this property can display only text information (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). 
But you can use `Manufacturer` and `ARPURLINFOABOUT` to achieve something similar - in ARP you will see field Publisher with URL link which you set in `ARPURLINFOABOUT`.